# Cannot convert from Object to Int

Tags: c++, gridview

Have the following code, designed to change the text value of the field based on the Int present (i.e. if the Int is 1 then display "Big Cheese" instead.

Gives the following Errors:

> Error 4 The best overloaded method match for
>   'MultiviewTester.order_details.FieldDisplay(int)' has some invalid
>   arguments Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'int'

.aspx Page Code:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#FieldDisplay(Eval("pizza_id")) %>'>
    </asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Code Behind

```
protected string FieldDisplay(int pizza_id)
    {
        string rtn = "DefaultValue";

            if (pizza_id == 1)
            {
                rtn = "Big Cheese";
            }
            else if (pizza_id == 2)
            {
             rtn = "BBQ Beef";
            }
            else if (pizza_id == 3)
            {
                rtn = "Chicken and Pineapple";
            }
            else if (pizza_id == 4)
            {
                rtn = "Pepperoni Feast";
            }
            else if (pizza_id == 5)
            {
                rtn = "Vegetarian";
            }
        return rtn;
        }
```

Keep getting error `Object cannot be converted to Int` . I'm not sure where it is getting this from as the "pizza_id" field in the DB is set to INT....do I need to do some kind of parse somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your method a little bit as below:

```
protected string FieldDisplay(object pizza_id)
{
   string rtn = "DefaultValue";
   int pizzaID=0;
   if(int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(pizza_id), out pizzaID))
    {
        if (pizzaID== 1)
        {
            rtn = "Big Cheese";
        }
        else if (pizzaID== 2)
        {
         rtn = "BBQ Beef";
        }
        else if (pizzaID== 3)
        {
            rtn = "Chicken and Pineapple";
        }
        else if (pizzaID== 4)
        {
            rtn = "Pepperoni Feast";
        }
        else if (pizzaID== 5)
        {
            rtn = "Vegetarian";
        }
     }
   return rtn;
}
```

I recommend you to use `switch` instead `if else` ladder.